# FontAwesome tags removed when switching between Source and Wysiwyg

Tags: wysiwyg

I am using http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/ - popular iconic font

When I insert "i" tag i.e.  it is saved only in source mode enabled, but removed from html when saving in wysiwyg mode.

How to avoid removing i tag? (using Ckeditor with Drupal 7 and Wysiwyg module)

Answer (score 9):

As Vic Nicethemer pointed out - the solution (for me) was to add `&nbsp;` within the `<i>` and `</i>` like so: `<i class="icon-facebook">&nbsp;</i>`.

CKEDitor removes elements that do not have any internal content...

Answer (score 7):

Adding `&nbsp` between the tags isn't the greatest since it's adding additional unneeded markup.

To do this a better way I suggest creating a custom WYSIWYG module to tweak the CK Editor settings.

Basically, create a module that adds a `ckeditor-config.js` for extra configuration settings with [`hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!wysiwyg!wysiwyg.api.php/function/hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter/7)

Inside the file you add:

```js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

  // allow i tags to be empty (for FontAwesome)
  CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty['i'] = false;

}
```

Here is a [CK WYSIWYG Tweaks module on Github](https://github.com/joetoday/ck_wysiwyg_tweaks) I created, download and install like a regular module if you have [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) w/ [CK editor](http://ckeditor.com/) already running. Then add any other tweaks you need, the tweak to stop disappearing  tags is alread there!

Answer (score 1):

You've probably enabled the "Limit allowed HTML tags" option. In this case You've to enable the "i" tag on the input format filter.

1. Open admin/config/content/formats
2. Click "configure" on the input format you're using
3. Add `<i>` on "Allowed HTML tags" setting

Comment: I am using Full HTML format with no limits - no matter. But even when i have added <i> tag it is removed (maybe by javascript) while switching. Note that it is saved and show up in content only when i disable Ckeditor using "Disable rich-text" link

Comment: SOLVED: i added &nbsp; between i open and close tags and now it is not disappeared! Think it some way parse HTML and if between i tags is nothing - it remove entire tags - very annoying

Answer (score 1):

I created an **unrestricted_html** format under `/admin/config/content/formats/` that I only give to administrators.

I unchecked **[ ] Limit allowed HTML tags** &  **[ ] WYSIWYG Filter** & was able to use the `<i>` tags successfully.

I also don't have a **Wysiwyg profile** associated with this format. My assumption is that as an administrator, more likely than not, they know how to write raw html.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method of forcing CKEditor not to strip out empty `<i>` without adding a new text format (or exposing your site to insecure code):

1. Edit your CKEditor profile. *(For me, it was `admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Advanced`.)*
2. Scroll down to the bottom and expand the "Advanced options" fieldset.
3. In the "Custom JavaScript configuration" field, add the following:

   `config.allowedContent = true;
   CKEDITOR.dtd.$removeEmpty.i = 0;`

*(These instructions originaled from https://www.drupal.org/node/2385795#comment-9681661 with some minor tweaks.)*